# What is an emulator POD?

Tags: pcb-design, embedded, control-system, cpu, computer-architecture

Jack Ganssle - The Firmware Handbook States

```
Orient the CPU chip so it’s possible to connect an emulator, if you’re using one. Sometimes
the target board is so buried inside of a cabinet that access is limited at best. Most emulator
pods have form factors that favor a particular direction of insertion.
Watch out for vertical clearance, too! A pod stacked atop a large SMT adaptor might need 4
to 6 inches of space above the board. Be sure there’s nothing over the top of the board that
will interfere with the pod.
```

What does he mean by emulator POD? What exactly is being emulated? If I am actually plugging a CPU into something, my intuition is that nothing is being emulated.

Can someone give me an example of a use case of an emulator pod in the embedded system design process?

Comment: https://microchipdeveloper.com/realice:pod-hw

Comment: This is from before the single wire debugging era. Big clumsy things that cost as much as a car, in order to get real-time trace.

Answer (score 4):

I have witnessed this type of hardware emulator used about 20 years ago at HP Personal Software Division... in the days of single core 80286... The target system's CPU chip (such as intel x86) is replaced by the hardware emulator pod. Physically the hardware emulator consists of a box (maybe the size of a big laptop computer) and a pod, which is a smaller connector that fits into the CPU socket. In use, the CPU is physically removed from its socket on the motherboard, and replaced by the hardware emulator's pod. Inside the hardware emulator's main cabinet is an FPGA or a specialized ASIC that is equivalent to the target CPU, but with some additional debug capabilities. Then that is in turn connected to a second computer, which is used as the debug console.

This combination of a small connector pod together with a larger cabinet, gives a firmware developer direct access to the internal workings of the target CPU, running at full speed. Mostly we try to avoid this due to the very high cost and awkward interface of such a system. But if you're debugging a system and need to set a breakpoint on a kernel interrupt, and there simply are no debug tools at that level, then a hardware emulator may be the only way out.

What Jack Ganssle is referring to here is that the emulator's pod is physically larger than the target CPU which it replaces, and may have some additional mechanical requirements that the motherboard designer should take into account. Specifically, the target CPU does not have an umbilical cord linking it to a whole other cabinet of electronics. This consideration is applicable if you were designing an 80286/80386/80486 motherboard 20 years ago, and have a hardware emulator in mind.

Not every CPU has or requires a hardware emulator. Many newer CPUs are designed with hardware debug facilities on-chip. For today I'd interpret Jack Ganssle's advise as meaning you should consider what hardware debug tools are available for your target CPU, and ensure that your PCB design can support those tools. If you look for example at STMicro's STM32F ["Nucleo-F401"](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html) evaluation boards, they have a software debug header that supports a debug protocol specific to that model CPU. When you design your own STM32 based board, it's smart to include that debug header as part of your design. Even if you leave the debug header unpopulated, even if you never end up needing it. Having the debug header available, someplace where you can reach it, gives you the capability to examine and debug the firmware directly on the target board.

Comment: Nitpick: The STM32's debug protocols (JTAG and SWD) are not model specific, but ARM-specific. The ARM JTAG protocol is (obviously) based on JTAG, and SWD is designed by ARM, and is basically a low-pin-JTAG-replacement. You connect the JTAG/SWD header with a debug probe (sometimes wrongly called an "emulator") which is in turn connected to a PC, typically via USB or Ethernet, which allows you to debug the CPU in-system, in realtime. Modern x86 CPUs and also larger ARM SoC's (as found in smartphones) work similarly.

Comment: Been a long time since I've seem a CPU emulator pod around our place.

Comment: @Erlkoenig The persistent argument for using emulators over single-wire debugging was that single-wire debugging is using cycle stealing and so pedantically, it isn't "real-time", since you'll be missing out 1 cycle in 200 or some such.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thank you very much. If you think Jack Ganssle's book is outdated, would you suggest a more modern version?